# Suggestion to combination generator

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I want to write combination generator. Generator must create combination in this format AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE

It can be letters or numbers but only from my array

```
$input = array("2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M");
```

In one sector for example AAAAA can't be 5 the same letters or numbers

And in all 5 sectors can't be 15 the same letters or numbers

After generate script check in MySQL is it unique combination and when database haven't got record with this combo show in browser.

It works but not enought good because after 641376 records in MySQL script give me info to try again because generated combo is in database.

How to fix that because i know is it more combination than 641376 but my generator can create only the same with database

I attached code to my script

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

$input = array("2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M");

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
$part1 = $input[$rand_keys[0]] . $input[$rand_keys[1]] . $input[$rand_keys[2]] . $input[$rand_keys[3]] . $input[$rand_keys[4]];

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
$part2 = $input[$rand_keys[0]] . $input[$rand_keys[1]] . $input[$rand_keys[2]] . $input[$rand_keys[3]] . $input[$rand_keys[4]];

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
$part3 = $input[$rand_keys[0]] . $input[$rand_keys[1]] . $input[$rand_keys[2]] . $input[$rand_keys[3]] . $input[$rand_keys[4]];

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
$part4 = $input[$rand_keys[0]] . $input[$rand_keys[1]] . $input[$rand_keys[2]] . $input[$rand_keys[3]] . $input[$rand_keys[4]];

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
$part5 = $input[$rand_keys[0]] . $input[$rand_keys[1]] . $input[$rand_keys[2]] . $input[$rand_keys[3]] . $input[$rand_keys[4]];

if (substr_count($part1, '1') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 1 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, '2') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 2 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, '3') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 3 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, '4') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 4 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, '6') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 6 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, '7') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 7 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, '8') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 8 w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'Q') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Q w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'W') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo W w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'R') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo R w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'T') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo T w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'Y') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Y w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'P') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo P w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'D') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo D w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'F') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo F w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'G') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo G w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'H') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo H w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'J') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo J w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'K') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo K w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'X') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo X w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'C') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo C w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'V') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo V w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'B') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo B w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part1, 'M') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo M w czesci pierwszej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '2') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 2 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '3') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 3 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '4') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 4 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '6') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 6 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '7') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 7 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '8') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 8 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, '9') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 9 w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'Q') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Q w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'W') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo W w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'R') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo R w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'T') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo T w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'Y') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Y w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'P') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo P w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'D') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo D w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'F') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo F w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'G') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo G w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'H') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo H w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'J') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo J w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'K') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo K w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'X') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo X w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'C') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo C w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'V') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo V w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'B') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo B w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part2, 'M') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo M w czesci drugiej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '2') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 2 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '3') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 3 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '4') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 4 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '6') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 6 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '7') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 7 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '8') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 8 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, '9') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 9 w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'Q') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Q w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'W') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo W w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'R') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo R w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'T') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo T w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'Y') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Y w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'P') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo P w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'D') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo D w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'F') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo F w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'G') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo G w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'H') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo H w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'J') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo J w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'K') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo K w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'X') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo X w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'C') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo C w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'V') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo V w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'B') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo B w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part3, 'M') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo M w czesci trzeciej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '2') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 2 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '3') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 3 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '4') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 4 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '6') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 6 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '7') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 7 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '8') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 8 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, '9') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 9 w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'Q') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Q w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'W') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo W w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'R') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo R w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'T') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo T w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'Y') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Y w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'P') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo P w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'D') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo D w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'F') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo F w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'G') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo G w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'H') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo H w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'J') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo J w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'K') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo K w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'X') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo X w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'C') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo C w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'V') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo V w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'B') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo B w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part4, 'M') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo M w czesci czwartej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '2') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 2 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '3') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 3 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '4') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 4 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '6') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 6 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '7') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 7 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '8') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 8 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, '9') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo 9 w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'Q') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Q w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'W') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo W w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'R') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo R w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'T') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo T w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'Y') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo Y w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'P') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo P w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'D') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo D w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'F') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo F w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'G') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo G w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'H') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo H w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'J') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo J w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'K') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo K w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'X') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo X w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'C') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo C w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'V') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo V w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'B') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo B w czesci piatej</div>');
elseif (substr_count($part5, 'M') == 5)
    die('<div class="error">Za duzo M w czesci piatej</div>');

$code = $part1 . "-" . $part2 . "-" . $part3 . "-" . $part4 . "-" . $part5;

$count_numbers = substr_count($code, '2') + substr_count($code, '3') + substr_count($code, '4') + substr_count($code, '6') + substr_count($code, '7') + substr_count($code, '8') + substr_count($code, '9');

if ($count_numbers >= 15){
    die ('<div class="error">Wygenerowano kod w ktorym jest 15 lub wiecej cyfr</div>');
}


$check_code = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bot_gen WHERE code = '$code' LIMIT 1"));

if ($check_code[0] < 1) {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO bot_gen (code) VALUES ('$code');") or die ('Error with query.');

    echo "<span class='code'>" . $code . "</span>";

} else {

echo "<div class='error'>You generate not unique combination.</div>";

}

?>
```

Comment: show some valid combinations.

Comment: Think what you're doing, before you start writing code. Also: _stop using the `mysql_*` extension_ It's deprecated. You should also realize that generating random strings consisting of 15 chars make for a vast number of possibilities. Generate them with a stand-alone script beforehand

Comment: You've got multiple issues to work at: first, as @SergioBernardo mentioned, the results of [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) are ordered (since PHP 5.2.0). Secondly you dont't want to use array_rand at all, because you allow for up to 4 times the same value per sector. array_rand will return five different ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question, you have two issues that are limiting the count of your results.

1. The result of [array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) is ordered. You could apply the function [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) on the result of array_rand() to avoid this problem, but
2. You won't use array_rand() at all. It will give you five different values, but you're allowing up to four times the same value per section.

## Alternative approach

Get an array of 25 random elements out of your input array

Check this array with your conditions:

- Is there an element 15 times and more
- Check every section, wether it contains only the same value

If one of the checks fails get the next array of 25 random elements until you've got a valid combination.

## Explanation of the checks

**Element with a frequency of 15 and higher**

Use the function [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get an array with the values of the original array as keys and their frequency in array as values. We sort that in descending order with the [rsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) function. If the value of the first element is greater than 14, then this check failed.

**Check the section of having only the same value**

- Split the array with the [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function in sections of 5 elements.
- Remove the duplicates in every section with [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- If the section contains only one element now, then this check failed.

**Loop**

If any of those checks failed, the combination is not valid and we'll have another try until we get a valid one.

## Code:

```
<?php
    $input = array("2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M");
    $arr_result = array();
    $valid = true;

    do {// create an array with 25 random valid input characters
        for($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) {
            $arr_result[] = $input[rand(0, count($input)-1)];
        }
        // check if an value will have a frequency of 15 and more
        $result_values = array_count_values($arr_result);
        rsort($result_values);      
        if ($result_values[0] > 14) {
            $valid = false; 
        }
        // check that no section contains only the same value
        $sections = array_chunk($arr_result, 5);
        foreach($sections as $section) {
            $reduced = array_unique($section);
            if (count($reduced) == 1) {
                $valid = false;
            }
        }
    } while (!$valid);

    // valid array, let's build the combination
    $sections = array_chunk($arr_result, 5);
    $parts = array();
    foreach($sections as $section) {
        $parts[] = implode("", $section);
    }   
    $result = implode("-", $parts);
    echo $result; // try to add this result to your database instead ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rainbow table algorithm.  It avoid collisions because it uses the result of the input to generate new hash values.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew the array_rand() function and just made some tests with it...

I've noticed that the results from this function are not entirely random: the values of your $rand_keys are always ordered and never repeated. I believe this is why you cannot archive all the combinations you need...

Try using:

```
$input[rand(0,sizeof($input)-1)]
```

to get your random values!